# Dudas sobre el siguiente codigo

Tags: javascript

Hola revisando la documentación de typescript me encontré con estos bloque de código y quisiera saber mas en detalle por que ocurre estos resultados ,el primer for imprime solo 10 y el segundo imprime la secuencia ?????

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 100 * i);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 100 * i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente es el diferente alcance de `var` con respecto a `let`, [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let) puedes encontrar documentación de ello en español.

Ahora bien, aquí va la explicación, como se menciona en la documentación, el alcance de `var` es mayor a `let`, así por ejemplo en en el código cuando declaras en el for `var i = 0` el alcance es global, la variable se "eleva" al objeto *window* en el caso del navegador. Este comportamiento no ocurre con `let`, ya que `let i = 0` no se "eleva", sino pertenece al for, su alcance es sólo adentro del for.

```js
for (var i_var = 0; i_var < 10; i_var++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i_var); }, 100 * i_var);
}
console.log("Valor de var: "+i_var);
for (let i_let = 0; i_let < 10 ; i_let++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i_let); }, 100 * i_let);
}
console.log("Valor de let: "+i_let);
```

Al ejecutar ese código, sale el error de que i_let no está definido, porque no se elevó a window, una vez aclarado esto ahora sí viene la respuesta:

Al término del primer for se muestra el valor de `i_var`, es decir 10 y cada `console.log()` del `setTimeout` hará referencia a ese valor, ya que como habrás notado, primero se imprime "Valor de var: 10", luego el error y luego se ejecutan los demás `console.log()`.

Y en el segundo for es diferente, porque si ya se acabó el for y la variable `i_let` ya no existe, ¿qué está pasando? sencillamente cada `console.log()` del segundo for está haciendo referencia a una variable diferente, cada iteración representa un valor diferente.

Por ello, a pesar de que la `console.log()` se ejecuta cuando ya terminó el for y `i_let` ya no existe, puede imprimir un valor, esta es la variable que se creó en el ciclo y su valor corresponde al número de iteración.

Answer (score 1):

La palabra reservada `var`, crea una variable la cual puede ser utilizada por su propio `scope` ( alcanze ) y por funciones **DENTRO** de su scope, en cambio la palabra `let`, se limita solo a su propio scope.

### Ejemplo de `var`:

```
(function() {
var f = "Hola";
(function(){
console.log(f); // Muestra correctamente
})(); 
})();
```

### Ejemplo de `let`:

```
(function() {
    let f = "Hola";
    (function(){
    console.log(f); // NO muestra correctamente
    })(); 
    })();
```